# Django MySQLClient pip compile failure on Linux

Tags: python, linux, django, gcc, pip

Django documentation as of v1.8 recommends using mysqlclient connector for the framework.  I'm attempting to pip install the package on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 and running into a GCC error that I'm unable to find reference to.  I'm not an expert on compiling software, so was hoping somebody can see the solution.

I believe I'm getting a linking error.  I have installed distro specific mysql headers, but it looked like they were only applicable to Python 2.7.x.

Not sure how much of this is useful so apologies for the long paste, but here's the error log:

```
Using version 1.3.6 (newest of versions: 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0)
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mysqlclient/mysqlclient-1.3.6.tar.gz#md5=58d7c9c617a4286a88db290e7857d3aa (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/)
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pycharm-packaging4.tmp/mysqlclient/setup.py) egg_info for package mysqlclient
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Source in /tmp/pycharm-packaging4.tmp/mysqlclient has version 1.3.6, which satisfies requirement mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient
Running command /home/tim/BingVEnv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging4.tmp/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4bp9npvl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/tim/BingVEnv/include/site/python3.4
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,6,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/tim/BingVEnv/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /home/tim/BingVEnv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging4.tmp/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4bp9npvl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/tim/BingVEnv/include/site/python3.4:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,6,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/tim/BingVEnv/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.cpython-34m.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're missing zlib; you'll want to install it: `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

I also suggest reading over the README and confirming you have all other dependencies met: https://github.com/dccmx/mysqldb/blob/master/README

Also, I suggest using `mysqlclient` over `MySQLdb` as its a fork of MySQLdb and [what Django recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers).

Comment: thanks a ton, that was the one dep I was missing.  thanks for "teaching me to fish", as well!

Answer (score -1):

using this MySQL Connector worked for me:

- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html

Comment: true - it's more of a comment and i would have posted it as such but apparently i don't have enough points to make comments. i struggled a lot with mysql connectors like the op and while most of them are outdated and don't work with python 3.x and django>1.7 i wanted to refer the op to a working solution. although mysql connector may not be the fastest your benchmark is from 2013 and does not reflect the current state of connectors compatible to python 3.x as in OP's configuration.